# Sort of following data.

Tags: php, mysql, sql, facebook, twitter

**How to sort below data**

```
Black Tiger / HL / Regular G2 - 10x2000/2000 - 13/15 ()<br>
Black Tiger / HL / Regular G2 - 10x2000/2000 - 16/20 ()<br>
Black Tiger / HL / Regular G2 - 10x2000/2000 - 21/25 ()<br>
Black Tiger / HL / Regular G2 - 10x2000/2000 - 3/6 ()<br>
Black Tiger / HL / Regular G2 - 10x2000/2000 - 8/12 ()<br>
Black Tiger / HL / Regular G2 - 6x2000/2000 - 13/15 (0)<br>
Vannamei / HOSO / Regular - 10x800/1000 - 31/40 (50)<br>
Vannamei / HOSO / Regular - 10x800/1000 - 40/60 (75)<br>
Vannamei / HOSO / Regular - 10x800/1000 - 61/80 (100)<br>
Vannamei / HOSO / Horeca - 10x800/1000 - 8/12 (15)<br>
Vannamei / HOSO / Horeca - 10x800/1000 - 13/15 (18.75)<br>
Vannamei / HOSO / Horeca - 10x800/1000 - 16/20 (25)<br>
Vannamei / HOSO / Horeca - 10x800/1000 - 21/25 (31.25)<br>
Vannamei / HOSO / Horeca - 10x800/1000 - 26/30 (37.5)<br>
```

**Should be sorted like**

```
Black Tiger / HL / Regular G2 - 10x2000/2000 - 3/6 ()<br>
Black Tiger / HL / Regular G2 - 10x2000/2000 - 8/12 ()<br>
Black Tiger / HL / Regular G2 - 10x2000/2000 - 13/15 ()<br>
Black Tiger / HL / Regular G2 - 10x2000/2000 - 16/20 ()<br>
Black Tiger / HL / Regular G2 - 10x2000/2000 - 21/25 ()<br>
Vannamei / HOSO / Horeca - 10x800/1000 - 8/12 (15)<br>
Vannamei / HOSO / Horeca - 10x800/1000 - 13/15 (18.75)<br>
Vannamei / HOSO / Horeca - 10x800/1000 - 16/20 (25)<br>
Vannamei / HOSO / Horeca - 10x800/1000 - 21/25 (31.25)<br>
Vannamei / HOSO / Horeca - 10x800/1000 - 26/30 (37.5)<br>
Vannamei / HOSO / Regular - 10x800/1000 - 31/40 (50)<br>
Vannamei / HOSO / Regular - 10x800/1000 - 40/60 (75)<br>
Vannamei / HOSO / Regular - 10x800/1000 - 61/80 (100)
```

Comment: Is all of this data stored in one column?

Comment: Not a valid question. You're just asking us to do your work. What have you tried? What are the condition for sorting?

Comment: use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get results by below query but query will be slow if there is huge amounts of data.

`SELECT * FROM mytable 
ORDER BY LEFT(myfield,5), SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(myfield,'-',-1),'/',1);`